# Oscillator, angular frequency equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

[image: wikipedia screenshot]

I found the highlighted equation on the Wikipedia on [angular frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency), however it doesn't say how it was obtained, could someone please explain that?

Also, it says that the spring is massless, if it has mass do i simply add it?

Comment: The article says that *spring* is massless, not the object.

Comment: First question is answered here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#Dynamics_of_simple_harmonic_motion. Second question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_mass_(spring%E2%80%93mass_system).

Comment: I don't understand it but still many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you Newton's second law of motion :

$$ \vec F = m\vec a = m\frac{d^2\vec x}{dt} $$ where $ \vec a $ is acceleration and m is the mass of the object.

[image]

Now, the spring can be expanded by pulling it from the equilibrium position (x=0). But the restoring-force of the spring pulls it back (in the upward direction). This force is given by Hooke's law (in one dimension):

$$ F_k = -kx $$
where k is called the spring constant.

We can use Newton's law and write these two together.

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt} = -\frac{k}{m} x $$ or
$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt} + \frac{k}{m} x(t) = 0 $$
This differential equation can be solved to obtain solutions for x(t). The crudest way would be to try a function of t.
Considering $$ x(t) = A sin (\omega t) $$
where $$ \omega^2 = k/m \Rightarrow \omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

CHECK :

$$ \frac{d^2}{dt}(Asin (\omega t)) = - \omega^2Asin (\omega t)  = -\frac{k}{m}Asin (\omega t) $$
putting this back in the differential equation,
$$ -\frac{k}{m}Asin (\omega t) + \frac{k}{m}Asin (\omega t)  = 0 $$ QED.